# calculate how many total rice required to fill chess 64 squares

Tags: c++

I just want to calculate how much rice required to fill 64 box of chessboard but problem is that if I reduce number of rows and columns then program runs fine but if I enter actual 8*8 rows and cols then it shows me 0
I think long data type is not enough to store my required output then what I will use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

long fn()
{
    int val;
    long i=1;
    for(int row=1;row<=8;row++)
    {
        for(int col=2;col<=8;col++)
        {
            val = i*2;
            i=val;
        }
    }
    return i;
}



main()
{
    cout << fn();

}
```

I didn't need entire code as answer please just tell me which data type I have to use or if I am doing wrong only suggestions not solutions.thanks.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to figure out why it's not behaving as you expect.

Comment: why does the column loop start at `2` ? your board only has 7x8 fields

Comment: also note that because of `i = val;` you effectively use the range of `int` not that of `long`.

Comment: I presume you are referring to this problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem. Why not just use the direct solution?

Comment: because 1 square is 1 thats why i skipped 1 and start from 2.

Comment: you skip a complete column not a single field. In each iteration of the outer loop the inner one starts at 2

Comment: it look like table but it starts from col 2 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a 64 bit `unsigned` to represent the result.

The C++ standard requires `unsigned long long` to be at least that size, so that's the one to use.

The answer, by the way, is

```
~(uint64_t)0;
```

Comment: unsigned long long gave me 72057594037927936 is this correct i don't think this is correct output do you have any other idea about my problem so please comment and thanks for you answer.

Comment: Why are you running the inner loop from 2?

Comment: if i run code just for 1 row and 8 col it should need to show me 128. Right but it shows me 256 and if i start from 2 then it shows me correct 128. what do you think it is right or not.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your code is computing a value less than 2^64, which is 18.446.744.073.709.551.616, about 1.8 * 10^19. The **unsigned long long int** can store a value as big as 18.446.744.073.709.551.615.

For the classical problem, you have to compute the sum 1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^63, which is 2^64 - 1, the same as maximum value for unsigned long long int. For this, modify the code as follows:

```
unsigned long long int fn()
{
    unsigned long long int val = 0;
    unsigned long long int i = 1;

    for(int row = 1; row <= 8; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col <= 8; col++)
        {
            val = val + i;
            i = i * 2;
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: "the same as maximum value for unsigned long long int" - not necessarily

Comment: @Bathsheba you mean that it depends on the architecture?

Comment: Almost, the standard sets a minimum range, that's all, which is why I was careful to write my answer in the way I did.

Comment: @vasile_t i run your code to check just for 1 row and 8 cols to test your code show me 255 as result of 1 row which should be 128.

Comment: @shoaibsabir Well, from my understanding, if you reduce the scenario to 1 row and 8 cols, the result shall be 1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^7 = 255, i.e 1 item on first square, 2 on the second, 4 on the third, ..., 128 on the 8th. Do I get it wrong?

Comment: according to problem it is double not square means we have to multiply every previous grain with 2 instead of taking square of previous number.

Comment: @vasile_t i recommend you as a proof https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem

Comment: @shoaibsabir got you, but still, the result for 1 row and 8 cols is 255, and so is proved on the link you provided? You did something wrong or we have some different understanding.

Comment: @vasile_t if you are using your above code then it will 255 but if you consider my code then it will show 128.

Comment: @shoaibsabir maybe because you start the second for loop from 2 ```for(int col=2;col<=8;col++)``` ?

Comment: because i want that result i just don't know how to store large amount of integers as a return.